# Bearing and Distances Question

Tags: trigonometry

I don't really understand this question. Please help me, a diagram would be appropriate too.

A plane flies from $A$ to $B$, a distance of $120~\text{km}$ on a bearing of $035^\circ$. It then changes direction and flies to $C$, a further distance of $200 ~\text{km}$ on a bearing of $125^\circ$.

Find:

(i)  the distance $AC$, to the nearest kilometer;

(ii) the bearing of $C$ from $A$;

(iii) If the plane now flies directly from $C$ to $A$, what is the shortest distance between the plane and $B$?

I tried to solve (i) and (ii) but (iii) makes no sense at all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Are the bearings given in mils?

Comment: They are given in degrees @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question.  You should include your attempts at the first two parts of the question.  The way I read the third question is of all the points on the line segment $\overline{AC}$, which is the closest one to point $B$?

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig, I solved everything now.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. What do you notice about the degrees?
2. Use vectors to express each of the components, then close the resulting figure.  What do you notice?
3. Once you find the distance between $\overline {AC}$, the bearing will follow.